# Dynamic Countdown Clock HTML (5 days from open)

Tags: html, email, dynamic, time, automation

Is there a way I can create a dynamic countdown clock in an email? By dynamic, I mean that the clock would countdown 7 days from today.

For example, we have an automated service that sends email (HTML) on a daily basis. Once someone hits a certain criteria, I would like to send them an email with a countdown clock from when it was sent. So if person A meets the criteria on a Monday, the email will trigger and their countdown clock would show time until Friday. If person B meets the criteria on a Tuesday, the email will trigger and their countdown clock will show time until Saturday.

Is this even possible to do in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Use the link `http://demo.web4pro.net/builder/count-down-black/gif.php?time=November%2012,%202016%2000:00&amp;color=ffffff&amp;timezone=036` in your img tag src link
like this:

```
<img alt="" style="border: 0 none;" src="http://demo.web4pro.net/builder/count-down-black/gif.php?time=November 11, 2016 00:00&amp;color=ffffff&amp;timezone=036" width="500">
```